# Looking for source of quote: People that cannot distinguish rocks from coconuts exhibit a pitiable but praiseworthy tendency to die ,,,

Tags: epistemology

I'd like to find the author and source of a quote. I recall it as:

People that cannot distinguish rocks from coconuts exhibit a pitiable but praiseworthy tendency to die before reproducing their kind.

Comment: I'm thinking Quine, but I don't know the source nor exact quote.

Comment: I face a similar hurdle on more occasions than I feel is appropriate to mention. Since I'm *not* getting paid to do philosophy, it's a no-brainer why I'm stuck. What's your excuse, mon ami?

Comment: The closest I can find to this is Quine's "Creatures inveterately wrong in their inductions have a pathetic but praiseworthy tendency to die before reproducing their kind." From the paper "Natural Kinds" in his collection *Ontological Relativity and Other Essays*.

Comment: My undergraduate lecturer said something similar about people who don't believe in IBE and induction (that they would always be late to class anyway). Everyone uses these ways of thinking; some people pretend otherwise, perhaps to excuse their poor reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

On DuckDuckGo, the search term "exhibit praiseworthy tendency reproducing kind" pulled up a number of references to Quine.